# passing of data from dataset to variables and then to datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, dataset

I am trying MVVM approach. I have data in the dataset but I don't know how to pass the data from dataset to the variables of model class and then update the data grid. I want it like this first data from Dataset should pass to FirstName and then it should be updated to DataGrid, same for LastName.

C#:

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }

public string update()
{
    try
    {
        Auth obj = new Auth();
        DataSet data=obj.updateuser();
        FirstName=data.Table[0].toString;// i wants to add data from column 1 to FirstName and data from Column 2 to LastName
        LastName=data.Table[0].toString; 
        return;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
 <Button x:Name="ButtonUpdate" Width="100" Height="30" Content="Update"/>
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding }" x:Name="grid"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your DataSet is built but you could do something like that if you have only one FirstName / Last set :

```
FirstName = data.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
LastName = data.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
```

And you binding should looks like that :

```
<DataGrid>
   <DataGrid.Columns>                
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName " Binding="{Binding FirstName }"/>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="LastName " Binding="{Binding LastName }"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```